# How can I clean an anesthesia machine after a Covid-19 patient?

Tags: infection-control

Would I change sodalime after each patient or are the filters enough?

Comment: If you're working in a hospital or other care facility, you really shouldn't be asking strangers on medical procedure. Have you asked the company providing the equipment or does your region have a health & safety code on equipment in the vicinity of infectious diseases you should be following?

Comment: @Mast I'm new to the community, but surely this applies to many of the questions likely to be posted here?

Comment: @TomWright No, actually this question is very unusual.

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because the cleaning of respirators should follow hospital procedures.

Comment: @CareyGregory: indeed, but there might be a good idea to double check with procedures/recommendations elsewhere in times like this. (So I don't think this was a good closure.)

Comment: @Fizz Sure, checking for recommendations would be a good idea, but this shouldn't be the first and only place to check. I see no prior research and I think the question is essentially asking for personal medical advice, except in this case it's asking for medical advice for many people. You can vote to reopen, but you'll have to find 4 others to join you because I think it's a good closure.

Answer (score 12):

I refer to the American Society of Anesthesiologists

> 1. Does the anesthesia machine need to be decontaminated after use on a COVID-19 patient? We have HEPA filters in the circuit and the gas sampling line.
>
> Please refer to ASA Guidance that states, “After the case, clean and disinfect high-touch surfaces on the anesthesia machine and anesthesia work area with an EPA-approved hospital disinfectant.” The internal components of the anesthesia machine and breathing system do not need “terminal cleaning” if breathing circuit filters have been used as directed. Please also see guidance from the APSF on decontaminiation.

For further information see the American Society of Anesthesiologists [COVID-19 FAQs](https://www.asahq.org/about-asa/governance-and-committees/asa-committees/committee-on-occupational-health/coronavirus/clinical-faqs)

Answer (score 5):

This advice is about cleaning of anaesthetic equipment after a Covid-19 patient

> Short Answer: Cleaning procedures are the same for all patients if high quality viral filters are used to protect the machine. Discard disposable items – breathing circuit, reservoir bag, patient mask, gas sampling tubing, filters placed at the airway and elsewhere if supply is sufficient. Wipe all exposed surfaces. Manufacturers’ cleaning recommendations are useful for individual devices.
>
> As noted previously, a high quality viral filter will protect the internal components of the anesthesia machine from contamination. Single use items must be discarded and not used between patients. Practices of using an HMEF and reusing the breathing circuit between patients are not desirable in part because it is virtually impossible to decontaminate the external surfaces of the circuit. Some practices in Europe are reusing circuits by just changing the airway filter after use with patients at low risk for COVID 19 infection. Manufacturers typically have recommendations for cleaning solutions that are safe and effective for cleaning between patients. Usual practices for surface cleaning are acceptable.

https://www.apsf.org/faq-on-anesthesia-machine-use-protection-and-decontamination-during-the-covid-19-pandemic/#cleaning